# 23.10 auto screen blank never happens

Tags: power-management, screen

In Ubuntu 23.10, Xorg session, I set "Screen Blank" time to 5 minutes as instructed in
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-blank.html

But the screen stays on all night, whether the system is running useful work or just sitting idle.   Auto-suspend works, but I want to just have the monitor to go off (to save power and not light up the neighborhood) while allowing background jobs to run.

BTW, when I change the Screen Blank setting, *no* files are modified in /var/log.  So I am wondering if the setting is actually changing anything in the OS.

I previously used Cinnamon desktop, where screen-blank worked fine.  But I switched to "Ubuntu on xorg" because of various problems with Cinnamon.  Could there be some kind of "contamination" left behind by Cinnamon which breaks the regular "Ubuntu" desktop?

Comment: v24.10 isn't due for release until October 2024 

Comment: Sorry, meant 23.10.  I edited the question.